# Python: requests_html html method does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

This is probably (hopefully) a simple beginner's mistake, yet I cannot find any explanation for what I'm doing wrong.

I want to scrape some content for a yt-video with bs4 and requests_html. both of these libraries are installed. however, when I try to run the code, it does not work. PyCharm tells me that the method 'html' as in r.**html**.render(sleep=1) and soup = bs(r.**html**.html, "html.parser") is the problem. could anyone please have a quick look into it and tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests_html import HTMLSession

video_id = "v8Yh_4oE-Fs"
video_root = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
video_url = "".join((video_root, video_id))

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(video_url)
r.html.render(sleep=1)
soup = bs(r.html.html, "html.parser")
```

etc

edit: This is the full error message.

[W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start chromium download. Download may take a few minutes. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 488, in wrap_socket
cnx.do_handshake()   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1934, in do_handshake
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1671, in
_raise_ssl_error
_raise_current_error()   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
raise exception_type(errors) OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in *validate_conn
conn.connect()   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
ssl_context=context,   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 494, in wrap_socket
raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e) ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Administrator.WSW41/Documents/PycharmProjects/YoutubeData/try_out.py", line 10, in 
r.html.render(sleep=1)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 586, in render
self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 730, in browser
self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
return future.result()   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 714, in browser
self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 306, in launch
return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 119, in **init**
download_chromium()   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\chromium_downloader.py", line 146, in download_chromium
extract_zip(download_zip(get_url()), DOWNLOADS_FOLDER / REVISION)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\chromium_downloader.py", line 85, in download_zip
data = http.request('GET', url, preload_content=False)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 76, in request
method, url, fields=fields, headers=headers, **urlopen_kw   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 97, in request_encode_url
return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 336, in urlopen
response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
**response_kw   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
**response_kw   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
**response_kw   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]   File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/588429/chrome-win32.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

Process finished with exit code 1

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the __full__ error message as text into your question.

Comment: I added it now, sorry for not doing so earlier

Comment: The error message is saying `Max retries exceeded with url`, due to a bad SSL handshake. This is an entirely different thing than the `.html` in `r.html` being wrong.

Comment: When you render the page, requests-html uses Chromium (via pyppeteer module), and download it if you don't have it. You have an issue due to this download. Maybe this [issue](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/258) can solve your problem.